# Ideals in the ring of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The set of all polynomials with real coefficients that are divisible by $x^2+1$ is an ideal in the ring of polynomials.

How come this isn't true of all polynomials? I think I am missing something simple, but could someone explain this to me?

Comment: what is your understanding of "ideal"?

Comment: No my question was how come the set of all polynomials divisible by x+1 isn't an ideal in the polynomials.

Comment: Ok. Why do you think that the set of polynomials divisible by $x+1$ is **not** an ideal? It most certainly is!

Comment: Prove that it is I guess then. My guess would be that it doesn't form an additive group but I don't know.

Comment: It _does_ form an additive group. Take two general elements $(x+1)f$ and $(x+1)g$ in that set and add them: $$(x+1)f + (x+1)g = (x+1)(f+g)$$Also, $(x+1)(-f)$ is the inverse of $(x+1)f$, and $(x+1)\cdot 0$ is the identity element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, this is in fact true for all polynomials. In general, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, then the set of all polynomial multiples of $p(x)$ (which is denoted $\langle p(x) \rangle$) forms an ideal.

For example, consider two elements in $\langle p(x) \rangle$. Since they both are multiples of $p(x)$, they take the form of some polynomial multiplied by $p(x)$. Thus, let us say that our two elements are $f(x)p(x)$ and $g(x)p(x)$.

Now, note: $f(x)p(x)+g(x)p(x)=(f(x)+g(x))p(x)$, so $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is closed under addition. Do you think you could prove the other property of an ideal?

Comment: Addition was the only part I was struggling with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a commutative ring then **every** $a\in R$ induces the so-called principal ideal denoted as $(a)$ and defined as $\{ra\mid r\in R\}$. In words the elements of $R$ divisible by $a$.

In $\mathbb R[x]$ we have principal ideals like $(x+1)$ and $(x^2+1)$.

Comment: It's also a known fact that polynomial rings over a field are so-called _principal ideal domains_, which means that every ideal is of that form (and that there are no zero divisors, but that one is kindof obvious).